# I can't seem to figure out the regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code. I am trying to have the regular express test the phone number for validation. With the current argument the function should return positive, but it doesn't and I can't figure out why.

```
function telephoneCheck(str) {

  let reg = /^[\d]{0,1}[\w]{0,1}[(]{0,1}[\d]{3}[-)\w]{0,2}[\d]{3}[-\w]{0,1}[\d]/;
  return reg.test(str);
  
}

console.log("function: " + telephoneCheck("1 (555) 555-5555"));
```

Can anyone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, replace all the `\w` (Matches any letter, digit or underscore) with `\s` (Matches any space, tab or newline character). I believe you don't won't letter in phone number.
Second, you need to add a quantifier `{0,4}` to the end of your Regex, just like you already did in other positions of the Regex.

So the final Regex will be `^[\d]{0,1}[\s]{0,1}[(]{0,1}[\d]{3}[-)\s]{0,2}[\d]{3}[-\s]{0,1}[\d]{0,4}`

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed the \w. I must of been thinking w for 'whitespace' or something. Thanks!

Comment: happy I could help. If this answered your question, please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because your regex is nonsense.

1. No need for `[]` for single group (`[\d]{0,1}` can be just `\d?`
2. `\w` does not match spaces, just `[a-z0-9]` *in general case*
3. You match starting `(` but ending `)` can be followed by `-` or any `\w`

```js
function telephoneCheck(str) {

  let reg = /^\d?\s?\(?[\d-]+\)?\s?\d+/;
  return reg.test(str);
  
}

console.log("function: " + telephoneCheck("1 (555) 555-5555"));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to replace `\w` with `\s` for whitespace
2. You need to escape parenthesis `\(` and `\)`
3. You need to change `[-)\w]{0,2}` to `[-\)]{0,1}[\s]{0,1}` unless you want the unorthodox 1 (555)-555-5555 to be true.
4. The final `[\d]` should be `[\d]{4}` since you want exactly 4 digits at the end.
5. You can replace the `{0,1}` with `?` when evaluating a single character that is optional.
6. You don't need brackets around single characters.

Here's the resulting code:

```js
function telephoneCheck(str) {

  let reg = /^\d?\s?\(?\d{3}[-\)]{0,1}\s?\d{3}[-\s]?\d{4}/;
  return reg.test(str);
  
}

console.log(telephoneCheck("1 (555)555-5555")); // true
console.log(telephoneCheck("1 (555)5555555"));  // true
console.log(telephoneCheck("(555)555-5555")); //true
console.log(telephoneCheck("15555555555")); //true
console.log(telephoneCheck("1 (555)555- 5555")); // false
console.log(telephoneCheck("1 (555)-555-5555")); // false
```

Comment: Thank you! Everytime I think I have a grasp on regular expression I realize I don't.

Comment: There are lessons on free code camp that really helped me finally feel comfortable. https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/#regular-expressions